# How can I get the param?

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm pretty new working with angular and nodejs. I'm trying to upload files to the server and it is working fine, but I want to put the files on specific folder because I don't want to have files together. So this is my code:

```js
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
console.log('carId ' + req.body.carId) //here show undefined
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, DIR);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        FILENAME = Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname);
        cb(null, FILENAME);
    }
})

const _upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

exports.upload = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        _upload(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(error.message);
            }
            else {
                this.create(req, res); //in this method I can get the carId by doing req.body.carId
            }
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).send(error.message);
    }
}
```

In the code, with comments I marc where I can get the value and where not. The idea is in the funtion storage get the carId and put the file on /uploads/13 (13) is the value on req.body.carId

Comment: How do you send the file from your Angular code? How do you send `carId`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I create the data:

```
const form = new FormData();
    for (let i = 0; i < this.fileArray.length; i++) {
      form.append('file', this.fileArray[i])
      form.append('name', this.fileArray[i].name)
      form.append('carId', this.carId)
    }
```

In the service I do this:

```
uploadFile(data: FormData): Observable<any> {
    return this._http.post(`${this.apiUrl}/upload`, data).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```